# PHPStorm apresenta uma mensagem ao utilizar-se "include" e "require"

Tags: php, include, require, phpstorm

Qual motivo minha IDE PHPStorm, aparece esta mensagem com `include` e `require`:

> Dynamic include expression 'require_once $file' is not analysed.
>   Include expression is not resolved.

[image: Código PHPStorm]

Comment: @bigown adicionei a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando faz a inclusão de código baseado em uma variável, portanto o PHPStorm, que é um IDE que tenta analisar o máximo do que pode acontecer com o código, não pode ir adiante na análise disto, só durante a execução teria condições de saber o que será incluso aí. Ele dá ciência a isto.

Este código tem vários outros problemas.

Já começa com um [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) verificando se um arquivo existe, e que pode deixar de existir entre a verificação e sua invocação. Pode ser raro, mas acontece.

Depois lança uma exceção sem sentido, sem informação relevante.

E ainda inclui código não só condicionalmente, que já é ruim, mas baseado em variável. Até pode ser o certo a fazer, mas é raro. Tem que saber muito bem o que está fazendo, entender todas consequências disto, precisa ter um bom motivo. Se esta variável vier de fonte não confiável, aí abre uma brecha de segurança enorme.

Não vou falar do uso de SPL, porque é só minha opinião :P

Comment: Desculpa, nunca fiz curso ou algo do tipo. Então sei muito pouco, tudo que aprendi foi pesquisando e aqui. Como você fazeria um autoload?

Comment: Não sei, que eu me lembre nunca precisei fazer. Se um dia eu realmente precisar e não tiver outra solução, eu teria que ver os requisitos para identificar a melhor forma de fazer. Os problemas nunca são iguais. Sem requisitos não dá para falar nada.

Comment: Para se utilizar namespaces no PHP é necessário um autoload né? O meu objetivo é apenas esse.

Comment: *Namespace* é uma coisa que eu nunca usei no PHP, mas não vejo porque precisaria. O *autoload* é um recursos que pode ser usado de várias formas, é algo separado. Já vi sendo usado de diversas outras formas, não desta.

Comment: Não é questão de ser patético, é só inexperiência. Ninguém nasceu sabendo.

Comment: Eita fui imprimir algo pra ver e deu esse erro: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'library\Skreth\Http\Teste' not found in D:\skreth\config\config.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\skreth\public\index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in D:\skreth\config\config.php on line 9`. Você acha que eu devo fazer uma pergunta sobre?

Comment: Muito obrigado, mesmo. Você me ajudou a entender uma coisa que eu nunca percebi...Pra utilização dos namespaces **não precisa de autoload assim como você disse**, o que eu lia que dizia pra utilizar autoload era pra carregar os arquivos em pastas diferentes, organizando as pastas assim como o namespace e com os arquivos chamados assim poder utilizar os namespaces deles

Comment: O que eu acho uma tremenda gambiarra. Mas inventaram isso e tem gente que gosta. Não digo que não tenha utilidade, mas vejo muito abuso. As coisas podem ser mais simples.

Comment: Como você arrumaria esse código?

Comment: Eu não faria isto :) Arrumar ou fazer códigos sempre depende de requisitos, o que eu não sei quais são.

Comment: Desculpa tinha esquecido